# scalaで、Androidのライブラリ(aarファイル)を作成する方法について

Tags: android, scala, android-studio

Android Studioとscaloidで、アプリの作成はscalaでできたのですが、ライブラリの作成方法がいまいちわかりませんでした。
したいことは、scalaでAndroidのライブラリを開発し、AAR(Android Archive)ファイルの形にして、他のアプリ開発の際に参照することです。

scalaでAndroidライブラリモジュールを作成して、AARファイルを作成するにはどうすればよいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scaloidでとありますので、android-sdk-pluginを使っているという想定ですが

こちらのReadMeの「Generating apklib and/or aar artifacts」が回答となるかと思います
https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/blob/1.3.14/README.md#advanced-usage

同プラグインのsampleで[renderscriptをbuildしているサンプルがaarを実際に作っています](https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/blob/1.3.14/sbt-test/android-sdk-plugin/renderscript/build.sbt#L3)ので
そちらも合わせて確認してみてください